# Apache HttpPost isn't sending the query parameters?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, apache-httpcomponents, fitbit

I'm using Apache HttpComponents and for some reason when I'm trying to execute an HttpPost with query params, the uri isn't including the parameters.

Here's a code excerpt:

```
List<BasicNameValuePair> parametersBody = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();

parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair("response_type", "code"));

// continue adding parameters...

HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize");
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parametersBody, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

When I check the post's params with EntityUtils.toString(post.getEntity()), all of the parameters are there as expected... however when I execute the post it's navigating to "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize?null"

What do I need to do here? If it makes a difference, this is not for an Android app. Thanks for any help.

Edit: For the time being, I'm doing a workaround like so:

```
String uri = "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize?"
             + EntityUtils.toString(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parametersBody, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
client.execute(post);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask their support. My guess is that their server is broken and cannot understand POST requests with "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" that your UrlEncodedFormEntity is producing.

Their API examples show requests with simple "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" (as produced by many browsers).

Try to set content-type explicitly, there is a setter method

```
post.getEntity().setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```